# SessionStorage Retornando NULL quando inicia Aplicação

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho uma função que está vinculada a um botão, que salva um valor em `sessionStorage.setItem`, e redireciona para outra página.

```
Arquivo cliente.js

    pegaValorConta(id) {
     sessionStorage.setItem('id-cliente-conta', id);
     window.location.href = 'http://192.168.0.109:3000/conta';
  }
```

e quero exibir oque tem dentro `sessionStorage` na página `conta.js`

```
Arquivo conta.js

      componentWillMount() {

         console.log("Session: ",sessionStorage.getItem('id-cliente-conta'));
    }
```

O problema é que a primeira vez inicio aplicação e executo a função acima, a `sessionStorage` retorna `null`, ela só pega o valor quando volto para o arquivo `cliente.js` e executo novamente a função.

**Como faço para que a `sessionStorage` não retorne na primeira vez o valor `null`?**

Comment: adicionei da forma que você fez, ele espera os dois segundos para poder redirecionar, mas continua retornando null, na primeira vez. @sam

Comment: fiz isso que você falou também, na verdade eu já tinha feito antes, e ele retorna o valor que eu esperava no id, o problema está na sessionStorage mesmo.

Comment: mudei para  localStorage, mas tem o mesmo o problema. vou testar sessionStorage fora de uma aplicação React.

Comment: @sam testei sessionStorage em uma página html e js puros, e funcionou normal, então tenho que descobri como faço isso no react, além que já usei a função componentDidMount que é usada quando se quer carregar algo depois de redenrizar á página, e mesmo assim ainda continua retorna null na primeira vez também